# File type change (HTML input[type=file])

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Шs it possible to create a new file with specified type from the currently uploaded file for the input?

When I upload a file and trying directly in an `onChange` event to change the type of a file it yields at me that this is the read-only property thus I can't directly assign to it. So I wonder how I can bypass this and I can change the type?

Comment: You mean changing the extension ?

Comment: @robinvrd no. Currently Im testing uploading a .xls file in chrome which leads to empty `type` for that file.

lastModified: 1553002023697
lastModifiedDate: Tue Mar 19 2019 14:27:03 GMT+0100 () {}
name: "SampleXLSFile_19kb.xls"
size: 19456
`type: ""`
webkitRelativePath: ""

And I want to add its MIMe type to ty type but its read-only

Comment: It makes no sense to change that property, what are you trying to achieve? What is the expected consequence?

Comment: to have a type for a provided file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution to my problem.
Under MacOS chrome is unable to recognize the type of a .xls file thus I was unable to upload it. So I searched for the solution and gave up. Today by a mistake I found a fix for my problem. This solves my original question.

```
if (!handle.type) {
  Object.defineProperty(handle, 'type', { value: mime.lookup(handle.name) });
}
```